# Prove that $\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\frac{5}{n^3}=0$

Tags: limits

It is obvious that the limit is $0$, but, how can we prove that? 
What I did: We can see that $n^3$ monotonously grows to infinity, thus $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{c}{t}=0, \text{for some fixed } c$$

Comment: Basically yes, while your notation should use limits and not "infinity" in the denominator

Comment: You can prove this by showing for any positive $\epsilon$ that there is some $n$ such that $\frac{5}{n^3} < \epsilon$. Because the function montonically decreases, this is enough to show that it limits to $0$.

Comment: of course there are several ways to do that, but for starters just apply the definition of convergence.

Comment: yes, so basically you pick something like $n > \sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{\varepsilon}}$, so that later you bound your sequence with $|\frac{5}{n^3}-0|<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then $ \exists n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $\frac 5\epsilon \lt n_0^3$ by Archimedean property.

Then for $n \gt n_0$ we get $\frac 1{n^3} \lt \frac 1{n_0^3}$ $\Rightarrow \frac 5{n^3} \lt \frac 5{n_0^3} \lt \epsilon$.

$\Rightarrow |\frac 5{n^3}| \lt |\frac 5{n_0^3}| \lt \epsilon$ $\Rightarrow |\frac 5{n^3} - 0| \lt \epsilon$.

Thus $\lim \frac 5{n^3} = 0$.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you approximated $\frac{5}{n_0^3}$ to be $0$, since as $n$ grows it gets much bigger than $n_0$?

Comment: @A6Tech I didn't approximate it. See $|\frac 5{n^3}| \lt |\frac 5{n_0^3}| \lt \epsilon$. So I can simply 'ditch' the middle term i.e. $|\frac 5{n_0^3}|$ to get $|\frac 5{n^3}| \lt \epsilon$ and $|\frac 5{n^3}|=|\frac 5{n^3} - 0|$.

Answer (score 5):

For all $n > 1$, $$0 < \frac{5}{n^3} < \frac 5n$$

Now, assuming you've already established that $\displaystyle \frac 1n \to 0$, apply the Sandwich Theorem (aka Squeeze Lemma, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Start by assuming that $\exists L>0$ such that L is the limit of the sequence $a_n$. In such case, $\forall n>n_0 \ a_n$ is within an $\epsilon-$limit of L. Let's say $\epsilon = 0.01$. Now use the monotonicity of the series and show that $\frac{c}{(n+1)^3}$ is outside of this interval. Hence the only true value is $L=0$.

Comment: This *assumes* that a limit exists.